# when I add elements to the vector<int *>, I meet some problems

Tags: c++

here is my coding:

```
std::vector<int *>a;
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
  int j=i+1;
  int *p=&j;
  a.push_back(p);
}
for(auto &c:a)
{
  std::cout<<*c<<std::endl;  
}
```

I want to make the output be 1,2,3 ,but the output is 3,3,3.it seems that I have added  same pointer to a,but I want to add  different pointers to a by circulation,what should I do and how does the mistake above happen?

Comment: `j` is scoped to the body of your 1st for loop. The address invalidates as soon that loop is left.

Comment: I would think that p would go out of scope as soon as the loop exits, so this looks like UB.

Comment: Don't use pointers.  Just use integers.

Comment: @Carcigenicate `p` going out of scope is not a problem, `push_back(p)` makes a copy of `p`. The problem is `j` going out of scope.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ahh, good to know. Thanks.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: That's *probably* true (and explains the output), although the C++ standard doesn't say so. Really the stronger condition - the address is invalidated on each *iteration* is actually the case.

Comment: Thanks ,can you give me an example about how to add different pointers to vector by circulation.

Comment: @Kaiser: What do you mean by "circulation"?

Answer (score 3):

`j` has *automatic storage duration*, and a pointer to it is only valid in that *particular* iteration of the `for` loop.

In other words, you've created a vector of *dangling pointers*! The behaviour on your dereferencing such a pointer is *undefined*.

Consider a `std::vector<int>` instead.

(The fact that you see the same value repeatedly in the output is *probably* due to the C++ runtime recreating `j` at the same memory location. But **don't** rely on that. The C++ standard does not insist on that behaviour.)

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<int *>a;
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
  int j=i+1;
  int *p=&j;
  a.push_back(p);
}
```

`p` is an address in the stack. Moreover, `j` and `p` are valid only in the respective iteration of the loop, they are not significant anymore (`j` is destructed) as soon as the loop goes to the next iteration or ends.

If you really want a vector of pointers, the pointers need to be valid. One option is that pointers point to objects in heap. Another option is that pointers point to objects in stack which never go out of scope, i.e. never destructed.

Another, perhaps better, option is to have a vector of the objects itself, for e.g. `vector<int>`.

Comment: ,Thanks,can you give me an example on how to add different pointers to vector by circulation.

Comment: @Kaiser One can do `int * p = new int{i}; a.push_back(p);` This way, one has to invoke `delete` on all members of the `vector a` before it gets destructed otherwise there memory would be leaked.